# How to build an Angular directive that doesn't generate containing tags?

Tags: angular-directive

I'm having a little difficulty with this, I'm hoping maybe someone has some ideas. It's a very complex situation, but I'll try to simplify and nutshell it here.

Let's say that I have a directive that generates several elements, for example, a Label and a Textbox. This directive will need to generate different content in differtag ent scenarious.

The problem with a directive that has more than one element in it is that you can't use the "replace:true" tag unless you wrap everything in one element. "replace" doesn't like multiple root elements. If you don't use the "replace" option then the tag that generates the directive becomes the containing element.

I don't want all these extra tags. It's breaking my CSS and generating unnecessary content. So instead of this:

```
<div ng-repeat="s in something">
 <my-directive>
  <label><input>
 </my-directive>
 <my-directive>
    <label><input>
 </my-directive>
 <my-directive>
    <label><input>
 </my-directive>
</div><!-- End repeat -->
```

I want this:

```
<div ng-repeat="s in something">
    <label><input>
    <label><input>
    <label><input>
</div><!-- End repeat -->
```

I hope this question makes sense.

Comment: Are you translcuding the label and/or the input into the directive?

Comment: No, the directive is generating the label and input.

Comment: You can make it an attribute directive and have it manually add the nodes using jQuery.